# CorePlot: Data Labels with multiple layers

Tags: ios, core-plot, layer

I'm trying to create a plot with both text and an image as the data labels for each point. The code I'm using looks like this;

```
//Point symbol
NSInteger symbolIndex = interval.symbolIndex;
UIImage *img = [Common getPointSymbol:symbolIndex];
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 60, 50);
CPTBorderedLayer * imageLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
imageLayer.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:[img CGImage] scale:img.scale]];

//Point text
CPTMutableTextStyle *dataLabelTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
dataLabelTextStyle.color    = [CPTColor blackColor];
dataLabelTextStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
dataLabelTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica";
CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:point.title style:dataLabelTextStyle];
[imageLayer addSublayer:textLayer];

return imageLayer;
```

This works well for the data points that are initially visible on the plot, but for points which are outside the starting plot area only the symbol-images are drawn. If zooming out and forcing the plot to redraw, both layers will again appear. The same problem occurs if reversing the order of the layers, and then only the text layer is drawn. In effect, it seems sublayers are not rendered if starting outside the plot.

Is this a core plot bug? Is it possible to merge layers into one to mitigate this problem?

Thankful for help!

Answer (score 0):

`CPTTextLayer` is a subclass of `CPTBorderedLayer`. You can add the background fill to the text layer and then use the padding properties to position the text within the layer.

Comment: This seems to work but generates some new problems; if the text is wider than the image it will be constrained (and wrapped) within the bounds of the image. Is it possible to use padding to adjust the position of the fill if using a larger layer bound?

Comment: Actually, when changing the padding properties of the layer the background fill is streched or shrunk accordingly as well, so that doesn't work.

Comment: The sublayer drawing behavior is a side effect of the way Core Plot clips the child layers. Please report this on the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list) and we'll look into a fix.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Eric, I'll report it in the issue tracker :)